# Convert string ( Formname ) to System.window.form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in a C# windows project. All the menu items are stored in a SQL Table where I have columns as Title,FormName & DLLName.

On click of a menu item, I am fetching the respective FormName and DLLName.
Now I need to cast this string ( DLLName & FormName ) to window Form and show it.

Can you please help me on how can I convert this string to Window Form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me check that I got it right: You have some DLL that contains a custom class that inherits from `Form`. You want to load the type from the DLL at runtime, then create an instance of the type with the specified name and show that form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection.

Suppose you have a ClassLibrary1.dll which contains definition for Form1. I just tested this code and its working:

```
using System.Reflection;

private void LoadNewForm(string formName)
{
    try
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("c:\\ClassLibrary1.dll");
        Type type = assembly.GetType(formName);
        Form frm = (Form) Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        frm.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadNewForm("ClassLibrary1.Form1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you :

```
string s = DLLName + FormName;
Type myClassType = Type.GetType(s);
Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(myClassType))
```